# Error: could not find a distribution template for Parrot/stable

Tags: linux, heroku, parrot-os

[Linux Parrot](https://www.parrotsec.org/).

I try to install [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#set-up):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./"
curl -L https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install heroku
```

I get the error for the `add-apt-repository` command:

```
┌─[andrey@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Parrot/stable
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

1) Create file for example doc.sh with following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# Install dependencies.
sudo apt install -y curl apt-transport-https \
     software-properties-common ca-certificates

# Install docker.
curl -fsSL https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ debian-stretch testing" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-engine.list
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y docker-engine

# Run docker.
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker

# Add user to docker group for using docker without sudo command.
sudo gpasswd -a "${USER}" docker

# Reboot
sudo reboot
```

2) Make it runnable `chmod +x dock.sh`

[This article](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/09/24/parrotsec-3-8-docker-engine-en/) may help you with your problem.